# Android Studio - Gradle Errors NoClassDefFound when including libraries

Tags: gradle, android-styles

This has been happening too often and I am not sure about the reason. Would really love to know the reason behind it.

My app's gradle looks like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':Q-municate_core')
    compile "info.hoang8f:fbutton:${rootProject.FButtonVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:${rootProject.cropperVersion}@aar"
    compile group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: "${rootProject.picassoVersion}"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:${rootProject.guavaVersion}"
    compile "com.makeramen:roundedimageview-apklib:${rootProject.roundedImageViewVersion}"
    compile "se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:${rootProject.stickyListHeadersVersion}"
    compile ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile ('it.sephiroth.android.library:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.1.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v7'
    }
}
```

This builds well, but my app crashes with `" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mface.mcall.utils.Consts"`and its on a completely different class. **I have not even used the library that I have included.** Just the "compile" statement in the app gradle and the app starts crashing.

For example this:

```
607-5607/mcall.mface.com.mcallandroidstudio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mface.mcall.utils.Consts
            at com.mface.mcall.utils.ImageUtils.getImageLoaderConfiguration(ImageUtils.java:60)
            at com.mface.mcall.App.initImageLoader(App.java:32)
            at com.mface.mcall.App.initApplication(App.java:42)
            at com.mface.mcall.App.onCreate(App.java:27)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1070)
            at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callApplicationOnCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4708)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I remove the following lines all is well. I have no idea why; its good to know the reason so i can work around it.  This has been happening often with different libraries for example aviary.

```
compile ('it.sephiroth.android.library:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.1.1'){
            exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v7'
        }
```

I have tried the following combinations too

```
 compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.1.1'

compile ('it.sephiroth.android.library:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.1.1'){
                exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
            }
```

There are no gradle errors but the app crashes.

May be am missing something here?

The full app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    jcenter()

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mcall.mface.com.mcallandroidstudio"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }

    dexOptions{
       // jumboMode = true
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':Q-municate_core')
    compile "info.hoang8f:fbutton:${rootProject.FButtonVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:${rootProject.cropperVersion}@aar"
    compile "com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:${rootProject.universalImageLoaderVersion}"

    compile group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: "${rootProject.picassoVersion}"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:${rootProject.guavaVersion}"
    compile "com.makeramen:roundedimageview-apklib:${rootProject.roundedImageViewVersion}"
    compile "se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:${rootProject.stickyListHeadersVersion}"
    compile ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile ('it.sephiroth.android.library:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.1.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v7'
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody? THis is getting frustrating as some dependencies keep causing this error. Simple libraries like https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog, compiles, but crashes at runtime with a totally different class showing NoClassDefFound error.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I think it's something to do with Android Versions because it works on 5.0 but not anything lower.

Comment: Though i could not find a pattern, when i tried to move a few dependencies into libraries..Meaning, i downloaded them as libraries and used "compile project" - the crashes seem to disappear after that. I think it has something to do with the dex limit, but adding the necessary dex options did'nt help as well.